# Read gzip file from s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, boto3

Hey I'm trying to read gzip file from s3 bucket, and here's my try:

```
s3client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    region_name='us-east-1'
)

bucketname = 'wind-obj'
file_to_read = '20190101_0000.gz'

fileobj = s3client.get_object(
    Bucket=bucketname,
    Key=file_to_read
    )

filedata = fileobj['Body'].read()
```

And now to open gzip file I'm doing like:

```
gzip.open(filedata,'rb')
```

but it's throwing me error:

```
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

So I'm trying to decode it first:

```
contents = filedata.decode('utf-8')
```

which is throwing another error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I have tried decoding it using `ISO-8859-1` and then it's getting decode but again while opening gzip file it's giving same error.

Or is there any other way using which I can pull the data from S3 like using URL or something?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @AnonCoward python 3.8.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gzip.open` expects a filename or an already opened file object, but you are passing it the downloaded data directly. Try using `gzip.decompress` instead:

```
filedata = fileobj['Body'].read()
uncompressed = gzip.decompress(filedata)
```